# anonymous read-only access for MySQL / MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sqlite, mariadb

Sqlite is file-based, therefore it is possible to easily handle read-only access on the filesystem-level and allows to give read-access to everybody.

Is it possible to replicate that behavior in MySQL/MariaDB?

That means MySQL should allow "anonymous read access" to a given database to everybody.

Is it possible?

Comment: Define "everybody". Everyone on the machine? On your network? Anywhere in the world?

Comment: Everybody who has access to the MySQL-client. That means for MySQL clients using a Unix-socket, everybody on the machine; for MySQL-clients on the network, everybody who connects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create a user with username anonymous and without password and grant select privileges to all databases and tables:

```
CREATE USER 'anonymous'@'%';
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'anonymous'@'%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a user with an empty user name, like this: `CREATE USER ''@'%';` and then grant like this: `GRANT SELECT ON databaseName.* TO ''@'%';` which grants read access to only one database. You can use * to grant access on all. That way, user name can be null and not `'anonymous'`.

This is tested with 10.2.8-MariaDB.